# How to create an instance of a pre-existing model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I want to create a Task execution checklist app in django. Suppose I have a checklist with 3 tasks assigned to it. Now I want to have multiple instances of that same checklist so that at a time multiple user can cross off from their own instance of that checklist.

Comment: Here are the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a `CheckList` object with a reverse relationship `task_set` for the related `Task` objects and a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model named `user`

```
check_list = CheckList.objects.get(pk=foo)
# Force execution of the task_set query so that we can copy the objects
tasks = list(check_list.task_set.all())
```

Now if you have a list of `Users` that you want to copy this `CheckList` to

```
for user in users:
    check_list.pk = None
    check_list.id = None
    check_list.user = user
    check_list.save()  # New record saved to the DB related to the user
    for task in tasks:
        task.pk = None
        task.id = None
        task.check_list = check_list
        task.save()  # New record saved to the DB related to the new check_list
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The solution worked like a charm. Thanks again Iain.